# Network broadband

Tags: mobile-broadband, huawei

How to enable Mobile Broadband and connect to it from the list of networks
Because it is not visible to me in the list of networks which are displayed as connectable

Answer (score 0):

Which huawei dongle do you have? When you connect the dongle it should appear as a drive. The Linux driver should be in it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no line item `New Mobile Broadband (GSM) connection...` in your `network-manager` dropdown menu (I suppose this is what you refer to as list of networks), and your Mobile Broadband device does not show in `network-manager (dropdown)\Edit\Add\Type: "Mobile Broadband" : Create`, you have to install modules for your device.

For instructions to setup or install modules for the broadband device, if such exist, please refer to this site: [ubuntu.com wiki NetworkManager hardware 3G](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NetworkManager/Hardware/3G)